# Cannot compile sources apparently same

Tags: java, json

Hi guys I'm developing a Restful + JSON servlet, but I got a strange problem, if i try to compile my project source with this method:

```
public
static
WipdDBTable
parseJSON(String JSONBody)
{
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    JSONTokener jsonTok;
    Iterator it;
    String[] labels;
    String[][] fields;
    int i;

    try  {
        jsonTok = new JSONTokener(JSONBody);
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTok);

        labels = new String[jsonObj.length()];
        fields = new String[1][labels.length];

        i = 0;
        it = jsonObj.keys(); 
        while(it.hasNext())  {
            String key = it.next().toString();
            labels[i] = key;
            fields[0][i] = jsonObj.get(key);
            i++;
        }

        return new WipdDBTable(labels, fields);
    } catch(JSONException ex)  {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
WipdJSON.java:102: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
                fields[0][i] = jsonObj.get(key);
```

So I wrote a test class, with apparently the same source, but with this one I don't get any error:

```
public class jsontest
{
    public static
    void
    main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1;
        JSONObject jsonObj;
        JSONTokener jsonTok;

        s1 = "{\"lo\":\"ol\",\"json\":{\"1\":\"2\"},\"yo\":{\"lol\":\"lol\"}}";

        try  {
            jsonTok = new JSONTokener(s1);
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTok);

            Iterator it = jsonObj.keys();
            while(it.hasNext())  {
                String key = it.next().toString();
                System.out.print(key + "=>");
                System.out.println(jsonObj.get(key));
            }
        } catch(JSONException ex)  {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonObj.get(key);` return an Object, you need to cast it to a String if you want to get the value in a String variable. There is a [getString](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) method in the JSONObject class:

```
fields[0][i] = jsonObj.getString(key);
```

And you don't get any error in your *test* class as you're only outputting the value that is calling the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

Comment: oh my god, you're right I didn't look at what get method returns!

Comment: @user665766, Glad it help. Remember to accept an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
fields[0][i] = jsonObj.get(key);
```

Change it to

```
fields[0][i] = (String) jsonObj.get(key);
```

Now, you are casting `Object` to `String`. if you are not sure it is `String` always check with `instanceof` operator.

```
Object obj = jsonObj.get(key); 
if(obj instanceof String)
{
    fields[0][i] = (String) jsonObj.get(key); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get method signature is  look likes this

```
  java.lang.Object get(java.lang.String key)
```

**so definitely you have to cust it in your actual type.**

for example

```
String key = (String)jsonObj.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the error can be romove by replaceing line

`fields[0][i] = jsonObj.get(key);`

with

`fields[0][i] =  (String)jsonObj.get(key);`

and it is not giving error in second code snippet because you are printing it in System.out.println but not assigning it to any String variable

`System.out.println(jsonObj.get(key));`

so if you try to assign it in any String variable without casting it in String variable it will also give error.